# The csv file created not properly

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

SO i have been trying to create a simple csv file as code below but the csv file not created properly. It contained the html text that are in my .php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>CVS File</title>
</head>

<body>

<table width="370" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
    <tr>
        <td><h1> Ultracom </h1></td>
        <td align="right" valign="middle">
          <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" />
          <input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" name="btnsubmit" value="Submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" id="btnedit" name="btnedit" value="Edit" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" id="btnupdate" name="btnupdate" value="Update" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="btncancel" name="btncancel" value="Cancel" /></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
</table>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnupdate'])) {

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=edited.csv');
$file = fopen("edited.csv","w");

$row = 2;
$a = "a";
$b = "b";

for ($r=0; $r < $row; $r++) {
    $rows[$r] = $a.",".$b;
}

foreach ($rows as $details) {
  fputcsv($file,explode(',',$details));
}

fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? My code seems like mostly the same like other code to create csv file that i found so far on google.

Comment: **not created properly** could mean a lot of things

Comment: when i open the csv file, it contains:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>CVS File</title>
</head>

<body>

<table width="370" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
 <tr>
  <td><h1> Ultracom </h1></td>
  <td align="right" valign="middle">

Comment: nothing in the code posted contains any of that

Comment: exactly! but that's what i got in the csv file. Not sure what happen with my code.

Comment: must be included in something? using a CMS? template ?

Comment: i have updated my code above, pls check. i don't use any template or CMS.

Answer (score 1):

What a waste...

```
for ($r=0; $r < $row; $r++) {
    $rows[$r] = array($a, $b); // build an array of arrays...
}

foreach($rows as $details) {
   fputcsv($file, $details);  // use the array directly
}
```

There is ZERO point in building a string from distinct bits of data, just to explode that single string back into distinct bits of data later on.

As far as the rest of the code goes, if you're intending to download that csv to the client browser, you never actually output the csv once it's built. You'd need

```
...
fclose($file);
readfile($file); // dump to client
```

Comment: thanks Marc for the code but the csv file created still contained the html code not the array data.

Comment: There is **NO** way your above code could generate html like that. it's just not possible.

Comment: on top of the code that i posted, i have that html code which created a table and some buttons. that code that written in the csv file.

Comment: you can **NOT** output **ANYTHING** before `header()` calls.

Comment: again. you cannot have ANY output before a header() call. Your entire html document is output, and will utterly break the csv download stuff. You'll get your csv data... at the end of the html, and when you save the page, you'll get the HTML **AND** csv mixed together.

Comment: i see. so any advice how to create the csv file which only contain the array if the user click the update button?